# Magnolia menu items based on subpages

Tags: magnolia

Is it a way to access sub-pages in a Magnolia page template and link menu items (I mean navigation) to each page?
For example lets suppose there is a main page and three other pages: about us, contact us, and registration. Can I have dynamic navigation that adds a new item when a new sub-page is added to main page in magnolia admin?

Comment: Menu == Navigation? If yes, then see https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS53/Navigation

Comment: Yes, I will check it. Thank you

Comment: @JozefChocholacek I just checked the link. But how I can use it in my own template?

Answer (score 0):

Navigation generated from the list of items in JCR is out-of-the-box feature. All you need to do is add area with navigation into your page definition. For how to add area to a page definition, please refer to [documentation on templating](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Hello+Magnolia#HelloMagnolia-Creatingareasandcomponents)
Procedure will be slightly different based on which version of Magnolia you are and whether or not you are using STK.

HTH,
Jan